# syntax for spring binding of <input type="file"> using the tags

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

For binding the ordinary text box we may place code as:

```
<spring:bind path="ImageId">

                    <input type="text"  name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" id="imageId"  />

</spring:bind>
```

But in case if the input type is file then what would be the syntax for bind? and what is the position of `${status.expression}` and `${status.value}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is not possible because HTML spec prevents the setting of the file upload control for security purposes (imagine adding a hidden one preset with some critical file)

Comment: If it not possible by this tag methed, then please suggest me the code to store the image into db using spring & hibernate!!

Comment: example1:http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart example2: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/